# Primefaces p:tabMenu align p:menuitem to right

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, tabmenu

I'm using Java EE with JDK 1.8, Maven and Primefaces. Regarding the [tabMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/tabMenu.xhtml) of Primefaces I have the following question:
How can I align the last menuitem to the right?
Please see my code below:

```
<p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.i}">
    <p:menuitem value="Login" outcome="/Person/PersonLogin.xhtml"
          icon="fa fa-sign-in"
          rendered="#{!personModel.personLoggedIn()}">
       <f:param name="i" value="#{(!personModel.personLoggedIn())?0:99}"/>
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="Register" outcome="/Person/PersonRegistration.xhtml"
          icon="fa fa-user-plus"
          rendered="#{!personModel.personLoggedIn()}">
       <f:param name="i" value="#{(!personModel.personLoggedIn())?3:95}"/>
    </p:menuitem>
    <p:menuitem value="#{personModel.usedAccount.balanceFormatted}"
          outcome="/Overviews/TransactionOverview.xhtml"
          style="float:right; margin-right: 30px; #{personModel.usedAccount.balance >=0 ? 'color:green;' : 'color:red;'}"
          rendered="#{personModel.personLoggedIn()}">
       <f:param name="i" value="#{(personModel.personLoggedIn())?123:94}"/>
   </p:menuitem>
</p:tabMenu>
```

This code snippet `style="float:right; margin-right: 30px; #{personModel.usedAccount.balance >=0 ? 'color:green;' : 'color:red;'}"` in the last menuitem still doesn't align it on the right side:

Currently the output is the following:
[image]
while it should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the following works (tested in the PF showcase on 6.0.x)

```
.ui-tabmenuitem:last-child {
  float: right !important;
}
```

Although it is better to not use !important and see if adding a styleClass to the menuItem or the tabMenu and use that in your selector works to (no time to try, sorry).

Update: 
As @mismanc and OP found out, `styleClass` or related is not supported on the `tabMenu` but a `class` is. So if you do not want this on every tabmenu

```
<p:tabMenu class="flo">
   ...
</p:tabMenu>
```

and use the class in the selector

```
.flo .ui-tabmenuitem:last-child {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Adding a style class doesn't work, adding a containerStyle is not supported: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1450...

Comment: Thanks for investigating. So in the not to distant future (pf 6.1) it will be supported

Comment: Yes ;) But your solution works as well now. Together with [mismanc](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1562723/mismanc) I figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

I have just checked the css that primefaces used. And I see that your css code is used for `<a>` element instead of outer `<li>` element. When I manually add your css to outer `<li>` element, it is working as you want. You need to find a way to add your css to outer `<li>`

Or, you may use

`<p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-10,ui-grid-col-2>`

- first element your `<p:tabMenu>` element without last `<p:menuitem>`
- and second one can be a `<p:commandLink>` element

  `<p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid" columnClasses="ui-grid-col-10 tabMenucssclass,ui-grid-col-2 commandlinkcssclass>
       <p:tabMenu></p:tabMenu>
       <p:commandLink></p:commandLink>
  </p:panelGrid>`

Check out primefaces [panelGrid](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml) element

**UPDATE  -** **This is not for score, just for answer you should accept @Kukeltje answer**

```
.flo .ui-tabmenuitem:last-child{float: right;}
<p:tabMenu class="flo"></p:tabMenu>
```

Comment: I guess I will try this ;)

Comment: I update my answer. I add panel grid draft and columclasses you can use ;)

Comment: This works but [looks quite ugly](https://abload.de/img/ugly0vbel.png) :D

Comment: yes you need to write some css commandlinkcssclass :)

by the way @Kukeltje answer may help you. I will test it

Comment: You're right :D I mixed both solutions up and now it looks bad :D But I'll try to fix this.

Comment: Thanks, this did it for me ;)

Comment: I'll added the 'update' to the answer above. You can also propose improvements like that yourself to existing questions/answers. That is highly appreciated since it improves the quality of the Q/A without it getting fragmented