# hide p:menuItem in p:tabmenu

Tags: primefaces, tabmenu

I'm using JavaEE with Maven and Primefaces and i want to hide (HTML hidden) a menuitem in Primfaces [tabMenu](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/tabMenu.xhtml).

Something like the answer in [this (prior) question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936505/primefaces-ptabmenu-align-pmenuitem-to-right) would be good:

```
.ui-tabmenuitem: {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

**Just another small hint:**
Adding a style class doesn't work, adding a containerStyle is not supported: [See primefaces github page](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for hiding them if I remove the invalid ":"

```
.ui-tabmenuitem {
    visibility: hidden !important;  
}
```

Tested on PF 6.0 and 5.3.

If you want to do it dynamically you can conditionally add a styleClass to the relevant `menuitem`'s;

```
<p:menuitem styleClass="#{bean.something ? 'ui-tabmenuitem-hidden' : ''}" value="Social">
```

and hide it with some script:

```
<script>
    $('.ui-tabmenuitem-hidden').parent().css('visibility', 'hidden'); // or toggle()
</script>
```

Getting the parent is not possible with pure css, that's why the script is needed (as far as I can see..). Use the inspector i Firebug or similar to figure out what's needed.

Either just put the script in the page for running at load time, or put it in an onclick-listener on a button (or somewhere else).